# can't open file from network mapped drive

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

When a user tries to open a file from the mapped drive he gets the fallowing error "The specified path does not exist", also the location starts with \?\Y:\

Can anyone help us out?

[image]

Comment: Is the location actually shared? Can you how us?

Comment: i can't show the whole dir structure, but all subfolders are ok, except this one

Comment: OK how? Can view them on the host machine, or as shares?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share anything else because of the data confidentiality